# Static text within text field?

Tags: javascript, static, textfield, tumblr

How can i keep static text within a `<input type="text" name="site">` text field, just like the tumblr account ***.tumblr.com here > http://www.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .tumblr text is separate from the input tag.

```
<div class="inputBox">
    <input class="hideInput" type="text" name="site" />
    .tumblr.com
</div>
```

So the class hideInput style would set the border widths to 0 to hide them as well as the padding. E.g.

```
border-bottom-width:0;
```

Where as the class inputBox style would re-implement the input box style, so it would have a border, padding etc.